# asp.net sqlconnection won't open

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using the following to retrieve data from a database but the sqlconnection won't open. It throws an error at `scon.Open()`. I'm sure it's elementary but I can't work it out.

```
public partial class populate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Integrated Security = true; Initial Catalog = populate");  

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {     
        StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder(); 

        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                scmd.Connection = scon;
                scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                scmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM populate";

                scon.Open();

                SqlDataReader articleReader = scmd.ExecuteReader();

                htmlString.Append("'Populate page:'");                

                if (articleReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (articleReader.Read())
                    {
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["dateTime"]);
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["firstName"]);
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["lastName"]);
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["address"]);
                        htmlString.Append(articleReader["details"]);                       
                    }
                    populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });
                    articleReader.Close();
                    articleReader.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx
as one of my references. I'm also using `SQLEXPRESS 2008 R2` if these information are of any help. Here's part of the error message:

> Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Would appreciate if I could get past this and move on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow the connection logic here: http://dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection - connections and commands will be disposed at the correct times

Comment: Make sure you have all necessary auth modes enabled in your sql server instance. Here is a [guide link](http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/23/SQLserver-enable-mixed-authentication.html)

Comment: @Andrei: Thanks, it's already configured but I restarted it anyway.

Comment: @adaam: This looked promising, thanks, but I don't know how to create a 'namespace ConsoleApplication1' method.

Comment: Can you connect to `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` with Management Studio? If yes: what **databases** do you actually see in your server? Or if not: what error do you get when trying to connect?

Comment: @marc_s: I'm not sure how to do this but MS seems to only show .dbo files and this db is .mdf. I tried to open it with MS through File|Open|Browse but it causes an error: "There is no editor available for '[directory]\populate.mdf'. Make sure the application for the file type (.mdf) is installed." I think the error has just answered part of your question. The extension .mdf may not have been installed.

Comment: Well, have you created your database **inside** of SQL Server, using Management Studio? In that case, you would have a **database** inside SQL Server - which is stored in a `.mdf` file, but that's not something you should have to ever worry about and mess around with - you just **talk to the server** and tell it to use the `populate` database and leave all the other details up to the server to handle ....

Comment: See [this video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKWZZcrin5I) - this shows how to create database **on the server** (as it should be done). Once you have that, you should be able to connect to it using a connection string like you have

Comment: @marc_s: This discussion is extending a bit too long now but thank you for the great input and dedicated advice. I've now decided to call in a consultant programmer. He can view the video if he needs to. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Freebie advice: try to do your stuff **on the server** - because that's what SQL Server is - a **server-based** system. Try to **avoid** fiddling around with "free-floating" `.mdf` files - what *might* look like a good idea at first tends to end up causing more grief and frustration than anything else. Put your databases **on the server** where they belong - from the beginning.

Comment: @marc_s: I'm not a programmer. I'll hire a consultant to do it. It's only $200. Don't worry, I'm greatful for your assistance.

Comment: @marc_s: All the code was correct. The database just needed connecting in the Management Studio. I had to manually refresh the database when attached to MS otherwise it still threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have user instances configured on SQL Server (which is the default), you need to change your connection string to this:

Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true;

Comment: Strange, but that doesn't work either: SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = true; Initial Catalog = populate");

Comment: If that doesn't work, then I would investigate whether or not the SQL Server instance is running.  Can you connect to it through Management Studio?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Well it says 'SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)' 'Running' in Sql Server configuration Manager and I tried connecting it through the MS SQL Server Management Studio but 'populate.mdf' is not listed. Anyway when I comment out all of the above code, I get my GridView displaying data. Based on that, the problem must be easy to overlook or do I need make sure the database is linked to the Management Studio?.

Comment: I think you need to get the issues on the SQL Server side worked out.  I always start with the database and work out from there.  BTW you should move your connection out of the constructor and into the Page_Load event or you will have scalability problems.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I've already moved that connection. I'm looking at the differences between .dbo and .mdf databases. My current database is .mdf and the list in SM looks like .dbo. I tried adding AttachDbFilename=[Directory]\\App_Data\\populate.mdf to the connection but it gives the same error. Great effort anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

initial catalog=database_Name

select * from table_name

Is your database name and table name same?

Comment: Thanks for realising this. Yes, populate.mdf is the database and 'populate' is also the name of the table.